# What is the best option for creating a web app for searching through millions of addresses in a database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, database-design, gis, postgis

I'm developing a Node.js web app that will allow users to search through every school in the world (~7 million) stored in a back-end PostgreSQL database.

**UX**

The user will select a location on Google Maps (with optional fields such as type of school, N number of schools to show, M radius in km), and the map will show the top N schools within M km. The location that the user selects may or may not be a valid address, so Google Maps will translate the user selected location into latitude and longitude, and my web app will call `function findSchoolsByLocation(latitude, longitude, filterParams...)` and return a JSON object of the data from PostgreSQL.

**Data**

The raw data I am given consists of the address and metadata about that school, like this:

```
| Primary Key | Address -------------------------------- | School Name ------- |
| ??????????? | 3210 Wimberly Rd, Amarillo TX 79109-3433 | University of Texas |
| ??????????? | 5198 Jex St, Arlington, TX, 78019-4532 | Texas Elementary School |
```

After validating the address and metadata, is it better to 1) geocode all 7 million addresses as they are stored into PostgreSQL and use the latitude and longitude as the primary key, or is it better to 2) use the address as the primary key, and `findSchoolsByLocation` is somehow able to find the nearest N addresses solely with the string address, without the latitude and longitude?

If 1), I'm considering using PostGIS in local server (least code change), PostGIS in AWS RDS Postgre to better scale (I'm not familiar with AWS), or Google Geocode API (more accurate but is web service). I need to geocode a huge number of addresses, but I only need to do it once, and subsequent changes I will just update the geocode for updated addresses (obviously will not be nearly as much). I've read about the benefits and downsides of using web service vs writing to DB directly. Which is the better option for my use case?

**Looking for paragraph responses here** I want to write a report that would explain my decision process, alternative options, and handling risk and mistakes for implementing this web app, geocoding and database design:

1. What should I do?
2. What would I do if I made a mistake in this decision? How would this be calculated risk taking?
3. How would I handle conflict with my teammates in deciding which is the better solution?

Comment: There are way too many questions here, and most of them are off-topic.

Comment: Please: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3404097) Ask one question per question. Don't purposefully disregard protocols. Don't ask off-topic questions. [ask]

Comment: Which ones are off topic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking [help]

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is provided in the format described:

```
| Primary Key | Address -------------------------------- | School Name ------- |
| ??????????? | 3210 Wimberly Rd, Amarillo TX 79109-3433 | University of Texas |
| ??????????? | 5198 Jex St, Arlington, TX, 78019-4532 | Texas Elementary School |
```

> What should I do?

I think the following solution will work just fine:

- Extend your Postgres DB table as described with latitude and longitude. You don't have to use any of those as primary key, you just need to index your table by these new columns.

like this

```
| Primary Key | Address -------------------------------- | School Name ------- | Latitude | Longitude |
| ??????????? | 3210 Wimberly Rd, Amarillo TX 79109-3433 | University of Texas | ??????????? | ??????????? |
| ??????????? | 5198 Jex St, Arlington, TX, 78019-4532 | Texas Elementary School | ??????????? | ??????????? |
```

- Populate the latitude and longitude columns based on address using a GIS or [google map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). The majority should work fine, but you would have to manually fix some. You might consider adding a `GEO_ADDRESS` to your table for future purposes as well as for generalization of manual fix up into a general algorithm which will work without user intervention on a geocoding system used.
- Now given an address to show schools located within radius `R`, you can find geolocation as latitude and longitude.
- Using this geo location you can calculate a range of latitude (latitude_min and latitude_max) and longitude (longitude_min and longitude_max). You can do so by converting meters into degrees as described for example [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/04/27/converting-miles-to-degrees-longitude-or-latitude/). Alternatively, you can use this SQL query from [here](https://gist.github.com/robotmay/851250):

> Using an example table of 'addresses' with a latitude and longitude
>   column Replace #LONGITUDE#, #LATITUDE#, and #DISTANCE_IN_MILES# with
>   your search values

```
SELECT addresses.*, (ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(#LATITUDE#)) * SIN(RADIANS(addresses.latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(#LATITUDE#)) * COS(RADIANS(addresses.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(addresses.longitude) - RADIANS(#LONGITUDE#)) ) * 3963.1676) AS distance 
FROM addresses
WHERE (((ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(#LATITUDE#)) * SIN(RADIANS(addresses.latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(#LATITUDE#)) * COS(RADIANS(addresses.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(addresses.longitude) - RADIANS(#LONGITUDE#)) ) * 3963.1676) <= #DISTANCE#) OR (addresses.latitude = #LATITUDE# AND addresses.longitude = #LONGITUDE#))
```

- In either case, you might (depending on the supported area of addresses) have to handle the cases when your ranges cross -180/180 (Longitude around Antimeridian) or -90/90 (Latitude around the Poles) by splitting the ranges to before and after [discontinuity](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162602/creating-routable-grid-map-with-pgrouting-considering-180-180-discontinuity) for example. Unlikely you need to support those areas, but still.
- That should give you exact selection or if you prefer faster query such as `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Latitude > latitude_min AND Latitude > latitude_max AND Longitude > longitude_min AND Longitude < longitude_max` at least leave you with small enough number of options to filter it by the actual distance, rather than Manhattan distance. If it doesn't, you can safely show "too many schools selected to display" or "narrow down your search" to the user, but that has to be added to requirements specification.

> What would I do if I made a mistake in this decision?

You might have to develop a new solution, based on additional or clarified requirements. This is the nature of iterative software development process. The earlier you deliver something the earlier you fail and move on to the next iteration, therefore the simplest solution is a good one to start with and a prototype is a valuable way to confirm requirements with the customer.

> How would this be calculated risk-taking?

The smaller the step, the less the risk. Prototype frequently and you will avoid large risks. Say, for example, to evaluate performance implications of two solutions I suggested above (using simple SQL query to select based on Manhattan distance vs complex one to select on actual distance) you can create a simple test without real data and verify performance implications of each solution.

> How would I handle conflict with my teammates in deciding which is the better solution?

By presenting alternatives, open discussion and agreeing to the best option. If for some reason, this doesn't work, by escalating discussion to include your management.

Comment: Last time I looked, the Google Geocoding service prohibits storing the geocoded results in your own database. Many other available services have the same restriction. That would make finding a Geocoding service for this use case very difficult.

A second thought, most Geocoding providers cover specific countries or reasons. Global geocoding may involve multiple different services.

(Ask me how I know this... BTDT)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @BrendonWhateley, that's really amazing, even though I guess not surprising. In 1998 my start-up was shut down by officials based on the fact that precise geolocation provided by our PDA-based navigation system was a classified matter (you know, one can target something, etc). It is probably simpler now as you should be able to acquire it for enough money. I suppose that's not a problem if there is a business case behind it, so nothing to fear, right?

Answer (score 0):

Few notes:

There is no option to get away from geocoding (string lookups just not possible)

Are you sure Google Geocoding is something useful? It's just a geocoding tool, and as somebody mentioned they don't allow to keep geocoding data. You might need to use some other services (mapquest seemed to have plans with storing results)

#### I think your actual 2 options are:

- You either upload all your 7M points into some cloud service, they
  geocode it for you and let run spatial queries through API (check
  cartodb, mapbox). Google also have fusion tables, it's actually free, but there is limit on data size per table and data will be public (but the tool itself is great)
- Or you geocode data yourself and run spatial queries in your own
  database. Looks like geocoding will be the main challenge here. Make sure
  google API is right for you. Regarding AWS or local - go with AWS (or any other cloud) if you are in some small company or budget allows that. If you already have infrastructure and resources - probably it would make more sense to go with local.

Answering your 3 question - I think your main risk and concern would be the price. Just do a cost analysis of all services you might be using, I think after that it will be clear for you. To start I would check if cartodb (or smth similar) has a solution for you. If not then research which geocoding provider is right for you (the key is to be able to store the data you are getting). Then get an estimate from AWS. I think running local DB might be a headache, but probably will be cost effective.

Regarding technical part, I think you should use spatial types/indexes, no need to calculate distances with formulas. Below is a simple example on how to create, query and retrieve spatial data (in case you are not familiar or fuzzy on it)

```
--- set up postgis environment with docker if needed
--- (from here: https://alexurquhart.com/post/set-up-postgis-with-docker):

-- docker volume create pg_data
-- docker run --name=postgis -d -e POSTGRES_USER=alex -e POSTGRES_PASS=password -e POSTGRES_DBNAME=gis -e ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0 -p 5432:5432 -v pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql --restart=always kartoza/postgis:9.6-2.4


-- drop table schools

create table schools (
 country varchar(20),
 state varchar(20),
 school varchar(60),
 lat float,
 long float, 
 loc GEOGRAPHY
);

---- NYC schools
insert into schools values ('USA', 'NY', 'New York City School District 1', 40.7212744,-73.986311, null);
insert into schools values ('USA', 'NY', 'KIPP NYC College Prep', 40.8162614,-73.9260793, null);
insert into schools values ('USA', 'NY', 'The Young Womens Leadership School of Astoria', 40.7712631,-73.9241695, null);
insert into schools values ('USA', 'NY', 'Brooklyn East Collegiate Charter School', 40.6784249,-73.9658189, null);
insert into schools values ('USA', 'NY', 'N Y City Board of Education', 40.6933457,-73.9215088, null);
insert into schools values ('USA', 'NY', 'New York City School District 28', 40.7027487,-73.8079333, null);
insert into schools values ('USA', 'NY', 'School of Math, Science, and Healthy', 40.6394884,-74.0202785, null);


UPDATE schools SET loc = ST_POINT(long,lat);
CREATE INDEX school_loc ON schools USING GIST (loc);



--- get schools within 10km around (-73.9091706, 40.71163)

select S.*
,ST_Distance(loc, ST_POINT(-73.9091706, 40.71163))  as dist
from schools S
where ST_Distance(loc, ST_POINT(-73.9091706, 40.71163)) < 10000


---- Converting result to JSON.
---- It's a good idea to get it as GeoJSON since it's supported almost by any spatial tool. You can use http://geojson.io to visualize it

with result as ( 
select S.*, ST_Distance(loc, ST_POINT(-73.9091706, 40.71163)) as dist from schools S
)

,features as ( 
select json_build_object( 
  'type', 'Feature',
  'geometry', st_AsGeoJSON(loc)::json,
  'properties', (school, dist)
  
) AS feature
from result
where dist < 10000 
order by dist
)
------ main 
-- select feature from features
select json_build_object( 
'type', 'FeatureCollection',
'features', json_agg(feature)
)
from features
```